# Problem with outputting video stream from WebRTC

Tags: android, flutter, dart, socket.io, webrtc

I'm trying to replicate the project from here
https://www.videosdk.live/blog/flutter-webrtc
But for some reason when making a call, neither video nor audio stream is output. The logs are attached. Local stream is displayed normally, the server writes that devices are connected, added more logs, media stream comes.

```
`Performing hot restart...
Syncing files to device M2103K19PY...
Restarted application in 7 743ms.
E/BLASTBufferQueue( 2945): [SurfaceView[com.example.flutter_webrtc_app/com.example.flutter_webrtc_app.MainActivity]#1](f:0,a:2) isEGL=1, mPendingRelease.size()=1, mMaxAcquiredBuffers=4, currentMaxAcquiredBufferCount=1
[log] Socket connected !!
[log] Socket connected !!
I/BufferQueueConsumer( 2945): [](id:b8100000005,api:0,p:-1,c:2945) connect: controlledByApp=true
I/org.webrtc.Logging( 2945): EglRenderer: Initializing EglRenderer
I/org.webrtc.Logging( 2945): EglRenderer: EglBase.create shared context
I/org.webrtc.Logging( 2945): EglBase14Impl: Using OpenGL ES version 2
I/org.webrtc.Logging( 2945): EglRenderer: Initializing EglRenderer
I/org.webrtc.Logging( 2945): EglRenderer: EglBase.create shared context
D/libMEOW ( 2945): applied 1 plugins for [com.example.flutter_webrtc_app]:
D/libMEOW ( 2945):   plugin 1: [libMEOW_gift.so]:
I/org.webrtc.Logging( 2945): EglBase14Impl: Using OpenGL ES version 2
I/BufferQueueProducer( 2945): [SurfaceTexture-0-2945-4](id:b8100000006,api:1,p:2945,c:2945) connect: api=1 producerControlledByApp=true
I/FlutterWebRTCPlugin( 2945): getUserMedia(audio): mandatory: [], optional: [googNoiseSuppression: true, googEchoCancellation: true, echoCancellation: true, googEchoCancellation2: true, googDAEchoCancellation: true]
I/FlutterWebRTCPlugin( 2945): getUserMedia(video): ConstraintsMap{mMap={facingMode=user}}
W/libc    ( 2945): Access denied finding property "vendor.camera.aux.packagelist"
D/FlutterWebRTCPlugin( 2945): Creating video capturer using Camera2 API.
W/libc    ( 2945): Access denied finding property "vendor.camera.aux.packagelist"
W/libc    ( 2945): Access denied finding property "vendor.camera.aux.packagelist"
D/FlutterWebRTCPlugin( 2945): Create front camera 1 succeeded
D/libMEOW ( 2945): meow new tls: 0xb400007b520f5380
D/libMEOW ( 2945): applied 1 plugins for [com.example.flutter_webrtc_app]:
D/libMEOW ( 2945):   plugin 1: [libMEOW_gift.so]:
I/org.webrtc.Logging( 2945): EglBase14Impl: Using OpenGL ES version 2
I/BufferQueueConsumer( 2945): [](id:b8100000007,api:0,p:-1,c:2945) connect: controlledByApp=true
I/org.webrtc.Logging( 2945): CameraCapturer: startCapture: 1280x720@30
I/org.webrtc.Logging( 2945): Camera2Session: Create new camera2 session on camera 1
I/org.webrtc.Logging( 2945): Camera2Session: start
D/FlutterWebRTCPlugin( 2945): changeCaptureFormat: 1280x720@30
D/FlutterWebRTCPlugin( 2945): MediaStream id: dd96ee51-25c8-48ec-86a4-70f0ed150946
I/org.webrtc.Logging( 2945): Camera2Session: Available preview sizes: [3264x2448, 3264x1836, 3264x1472, 2688x1512, 2560x1920, 2560x1440, 2560x1280, 2448x2448, 2448x1836, 2448x1376, 2448x1224, 2400x1080, 2340x1080, 1920x1440, 1920x1080, 1600x1200, 1600x900, 1600x720, 1560x720, 1520x720, 1440x1080, 1440x720, 1280x720, 1200x1200, 1080x1080, 1080x720, 960x720, 720x720, 720x480, 640x480, 352x288, 320x240, 176x144]
I/org.webrtc.Logging( 2945): Camera2Session: Available fps ranges: [[10.0:10.0], [15.0:15.0], [15.0:20.0], [20.0:20.0], [5.0:30.0], [30.0:30.0]]
I/org.webrtc.Logging( 2945): Camera2Session: Using capture format: 1280x720@[5.0:30.0]
I/org.webrtc.Logging( 2945): Camera2Session: Opening camera 1
D/FlutterWebRTCPlugin( 2945): CameraEventsHandler.onCameraOpening: cameraName=1
D/CameraExtImplXiaoMi( 2945): initCameraDevice: 1
I/org.webrtc.Logging( 2945): Camera2Session: Camera opened.
D/CameraDevice-JV-1( 2945): waitUntilIdle: E. id = 1
D/CameraDevice-JV-1( 2945): waitUntilIdle: X
D/AudioManager( 2945): setSpeakerphoneOn(true)
W/FlutterWebRTCPlugin( 2945): FlutterRTCVideoRenderer.setVideoTrack, set video track to 2c74cf1c-b160-4ab7-ade9-91a046e35057
I/org.webrtc.Logging( 2945): EglRenderer: Releasing.
I/org.webrtc.Logging( 2945): EglRenderer: eglBase detach and release.
I/BufferQueueProducer( 2945): [SurfaceTexture-0-2945-3](id:b8100000005,api:1,p:2945,c:2945) disconnect: api 1
I/org.webrtc.Logging( 2945): EglRenderer: Releasing done.
I/org.webrtc.Logging( 2945): EglRenderer: Quitting render thread.
I/org.webrtc.Logging( 2945): EglRenderer: Initializing EglRenderer
D/libMEOW ( 2945): meow delete tls: 0xb400007b6ec4df80
I/org.webrtc.Logging( 2945): EglRenderer: EglBase.create shared context
D/libMEOW ( 2945): meow new tls: 0xb400007b66789f80
D/libMEOW ( 2945): applied 1 plugins for [com.example.flutter_webrtc_app]:
D/libMEOW ( 2945):   plugin 1: [libMEOW_gift.so]:
I/org.webrtc.Logging( 2945): EglBase14Impl: Using OpenGL ES version 2
I/BufferQueueProducer( 2945): [SurfaceTexture-0-2945-3](id:b8100000005,api:1,p:2945,c:2945) connect: api=1 producerControlledByApp=true
D/FlutterWebRTCPlugin( 2945): onAddTrack
D/FlutterWebRTCPlugin( 2945): onAddTrack
I/BufferQueueProducer( 2945): [SurfaceTexture-1-2945-5](id:b8100000007,api:4,p:1093,c:2945) connect: api=4 producerControlledByApp=true
I/org.webrtc.Logging( 2945): Camera2Session: Camera capture session configured.
E/BLASTBufferQueue( 2945): [SurfaceView[com.example.flutter_webrtc_app/com.example.flutter_webrtc_app.MainActivity]#1](f:0,a:2) isEGL=1, mPendingRelease.size()=1, mMaxAcquiredBuffers=4, currentMaxAcquiredBufferCount=2
I/org.webrtc.Logging( 2945): Camera2Session: Using video stabilization.
I/org.webrtc.Logging( 2945): Camera2Session: Auto-focus is not available.
I/org.webrtc.Logging( 2945): Camera2Session: Camera device successfully started.
I/org.webrtc.Logging( 2945): CameraCapturer: Create session done. Switch state: IDLE
I/org.webrtc.Logging( 2945): SurfaceTextureHelper: Setting listener to org.webrtc.Camera2Session$CaptureSessionCallback$$ExternalSyntheticLambda0@9095a16
E/BLASTBufferQueue( 2945): [SurfaceView[com.example.flutter_webrtc_app/com.example.flutter_webrtc_app.MainActivity]#1](f:0,a:3) isEGL=1, mPendingRelease.size()=2, mMaxAcquiredBuffers=4, currentMaxAcquiredBufferCount=2
W/FlutterWebRTCPlugin( 2945): FlutterRTCVideoRenderer.setVideoTrack, set video track to 5b76fbf3-86a6-4834-a953-6be67a3f0e63
I/org.webrtc.Logging( 2945): EglRenderer: Releasing.
I/org.webrtc.Logging( 2945): EglRenderer: eglBase detach and release.
I/BufferQueueProducer( 2945): [SurfaceTexture-0-2945-4](id:b8100000006,api:1,p:2945,c:2945) disconnect: api 1
I/org.webrtc.Logging( 2945): EglRenderer: Quitting render thread.
I/org.webrtc.Logging( 2945): EglRenderer: Releasing done.
D/libMEOW ( 2945): meow delete tls: 0xb400007b67133ec0
I/org.webrtc.Logging( 2945): EglRenderer: Initializing EglRenderer
I/org.webrtc.Logging( 2945): EglRenderer: EglBase.create shared context
D/libMEOW ( 2945): meow new tls: 0xb400007b67133ec0
D/libMEOW ( 2945): applied 1 plugins for [com.example.flutter_webrtc_app]:
D/libMEOW ( 2945):   plugin 1: [libMEOW_gift.so]:
I/org.webrtc.Logging( 2945): EglBase14Impl: Using OpenGL ES version 2
I/BufferQueueProducer( 2945): [SurfaceTexture-0-2945-4](id:b8100000006,api:1,p:2945,c:2945) connect: api=1 producerControlledByApp=true
I/org.webrtc.Logging( 2945): WebRtcAudioTrackExternal: initPlayout(sampleRate=48000, channels=1, bufferSizeFactor=1.0)
I/org.webrtc.Logging( 2945): WebRtcAudioTrackExternal: byteBuffer.capacity: 960
I/org.webrtc.Logging( 2945): WebRtcAudioTrackExternal: minBufferSizeInBytes: 4104
I/org.webrtc.Logging( 2945): WebRtcAudioTrackExternal: createAudioTrackBeforeOreo
I/org.webrtc.Logging( 2945): WebRtcAudioTrackExternal: nativeOutputSampleRate: 48000
D/AudioTrack( 2945): INSP: type=audio,case=1,set=0xb400007b6f0a5500,stream_type=-1,sample_rate=48000,format=0x1,channel_mask=0x1,frame_count=2052,flags=0x0,notification_frames=0,session_id=0,transfer_type=3,uid=-1,pid=-1
D/AudioTrack( 2945): INSP: type=audio,case=1,attributes=1,content_type=1,usage=2,source=-1,flags=0x800
D/AudioTrack( 2945): set(sessionID=0)
D/AudioTrack( 2945): set(): Building AudioTrack with attributes: usage = 2, content = 1, flags = 0x800, tags = []
D/AudioTrack( 2945): set(): 0xb400007b6f0a5500, Create AudioTrackThread, tid = 3819
D/AudioTrack( 2945): createTrack_l(51): 0xb400007b6f0a5500, mCblk = 0x7cb78f8000, mLatency = 84, mAfLatency = 42, frameCount = 2052, mSampleRate = 48000, mFlags = 0, mReqFrameCount = 2052, mNotificationFramesAct = 1026
I/org.webrtc.Logging( 2945): WebRtcAudioTrackExternal: AudioTrack: session ID: 737, channels: 1, sample rate: 48000, max gain: 1.0
I/org.webrtc.Logging( 2945): WebRtcAudioTrackExternal: AudioTrack: buffer size in frames: 2052
I/org.webrtc.Logging( 2945): WebRtcAudioTrackExternal: AudioTrack: buffer capacity in frames: 2052
I/org.webrtc.Logging( 2945): VolumeLogger: start@[name=worker_thread - 3420, id=50]
I/org.webrtc.Logging( 2945): VolumeLogger: audio mode is: MODE_IN_COMMUNICATION
I/org.webrtc.Logging( 2945): WebRtcAudioTrackExternal: startPlayout
D/AudioTrack( 2945): start(51): 0xb400007b6f0a5500, prior state:STATE_STOPPED
I/org.webrtc.Logging( 2945): VolumeLogger: VOICE_CALL stream volume: 11 (max=11)
I/org.webrtc.Logging( 2945): WebRtcAudioTrackExternal: AudioTrackThread@[name=AudioTrackJavaThread, id=68]
I/org.webrtc.Logging( 2945): WebRtcAudioTrackExternal: doAudioTrackStateCallback: 0
I/org.webrtc.Logging( 2945): WebRtcAudioRecordExternal: enableBuiltInAEC(true)
I/org.webrtc.Logging( 2945): WebRtcAudioEffectsExternal: setAEC(true)
I/org.webrtc.Logging( 2945): WebRtcAudioRecordExternal: enableBuiltInNS(true)
I/org.webrtc.Logging( 2945): WebRtcAudioEffectsExternal: setNS(true)
I/org.webrtc.Logging( 2945): NetworkMonitor: Start monitoring with native observer -5476376616873673344 fieldTrialsString: 
D/FlutterWebRTCPlugin( 2945): onIceGatheringChangeGATHERING
I/org.webrtc.Logging( 2945): NetworkMonitorAutoDetect: Network handle: 432902426637 becomes available: 100
I/org.webrtc.Logging( 2945): NetworkMonitorAutoDetect: handle: 432902426637 capabilities changed: [ Transports: CELLULAR Capabilities: SUPL&INTERNET&NOT_RESTRICTED&TRUSTED&NOT_VPN&VALIDATED&NOT_ROAMING&FOREGROUND&NOT_CONGESTED&NOT_SUSPENDED&NOT_VCN_MANAGED LinkUpBandwidth>=15000Kbps LinkDnBandwidth>=6803Kbps Specifier: <TelephonyNetworkSpecifier [mSubId = 1]> UnderlyingNetworks: Null]
D/FlutterWebRTCPlugin( 2945): onIceCandidate
D/FlutterWebRTCPlugin( 2945): onIceCandidate
D/FlutterWebRTCPlugin( 2945): onIceCandidate
I/org.webrtc.Logging( 2945): NetworkMonitorAutoDetect: handle: 432902426637 link properties changed
D/FlutterWebRTCPlugin( 2945): onIceCandidate
D/FlutterWebRTCPlugin( 2945): onIceCandidate
D/FlutterWebRTCPlugin( 2945): onIceCandidate
I/mali_config( 2945): @get_buffer_dataspace_setting: update dataspace from GE (0x10010000 -> 0x08020000)
D/FlutterWebRTCPlugin( 2945): CameraEventsHandler.onFirstFrameAvailable
D/FlutterWebRTCPlugin( 2945): onConnectionChangeCONNECTING
I/mali_config( 2945): @get_buffer_dataspace_setting: update dataspace from GE (0x10010000 -> 0x08020000)
I/mali_config( 2945): @get_buffer_dataspace_setting: update dataspace from GE (0x10010000 -> 0x08020000)
I/mali_config( 2945): @get_buffer_dataspace_setting: update dataspace from GE (0x10010000 -> 0x08020000)
I/mali_config( 2945): @get_buffer_dataspace_setting: update dataspace from GE (0x10010000 -> 0x08020000)
I/mali_config( 2945): @get_buffer_dataspace_setting: update dataspace from GE (0x10010000 -> 0x08020000)
D/FlutterWebRTCPlugin( 2945): onIceCandidate
I/mali_config( 2945): @get_buffer_dataspace_setting: update dataspace from GE (0x10010000 -> 0x08020000)
I/AudioTrack( 2945): isLongTimeZoreData zoer date time 1 Seconds
I/org.webrtc.Logging( 2945): CameraStatistics: Camera fps: 23.
I/AudioTrack( 2945): isLongTimeZoreData zoer date time 2 Seconds
I/org.webrtc.Logging( 2945): NetworkMonitorAutoDetect: handle: 432902426637 capabilities changed: [ Transports: CELLULAR Capabilities: SUPL&INTERNET&NOT_RESTRICTED&TRUSTED&NOT_VPN&VALIDATED&NOT_ROAMING&FOREGROUND&NOT_CONGESTED&NOT_SUSPENDED&NOT_VCN_MANAGED LinkUpBandwidth>=42305Kbps LinkDnBandwidth>=7440Kbps Specifier: <TelephonyNetworkSpecifier [mSubId = 1]> UnderlyingNetworks: Null]
I/AudioTrack( 2945): isLongTimeZoreData zoer date time 3 Seconds
I/org.webrtc.Logging( 2945): EglRenderer: Duration: 4004 ms. Frames received: 105. Dropped: 0. Rendered: 105. Render fps: 26,2. Average render time: 4577 us. Average swapBuffer time: 2520 us.
I/org.webrtc.Logging( 2945): CameraStatistics: Camera fps: 30.
I/org.webrtc.Logging( 2945): EglRenderer: Duration: 4005 ms. Frames received: 0. Dropped: 0. Rendered: 0. Render fps: ,0. Average render time: NA. Average swapBuffer time: NA.
I/AudioTrack( 2945): isLongTimeZoreData zoer date time 4 Seconds
I/AudioTrack( 2945): isLongTimeZoreData zoer date time 5 Seconds
I/org.webrtc.Logging( 2945): CameraStatistics: Camera fps: 30.
I/AudioTrack( 2945): isLongTimeZoreData zoer date time 6 Seconds
I/AudioTrack( 2945): isLongTimeZoreData zoer date time 7 Seconds`
```

Tried changing library versions, reinstalled flutter and dart.Tried the same way to make a server in the local network, turned off various protections.